# jQuery update a Div with a PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

I have absolutely no idea how to do this, so I'm just gonna go ahead and ask.

What I want to do is update the contents of a div with a PHP script I have in an external file, called send.php.

So I have a div like this:

```
<div class="classname">

</div>
```

And I want to post data to this send.php file, and then update that div with whatever the outcome of the PHP script is. Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple ajax calls, I normally prefer using [$.load](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load) as its grammar is extremely concise. Passing parameters as an object (key/value pairs) will cause it to use a POST request:

```
<a href="no-script.php" class="something">Click!</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.something').click(function(e) {
        //prevent the href from being followed
        e.preventDefault();

        //inject div.classname with the output of send.php
        $('div.classname').load('send.php', {param1: 'foo', param2: 'blah'});
    });
});
```

If you don't need it to be a POST, you can just add your parameters as a query string:

```
$('div.classname').load('send.php?param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">click</a>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
         $("#classname").load("send.php?data=someData")
         evt.preventDefault();
      })
    })
</script>


<div id="classname">

</div>
```

Some documentation to read:

1. http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

   - http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely!  Take a look at [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) post for instructions on how to use jQuery's ajax functionality.  You are then going to want to call

```
$.(".classname").append("Whatever results you get");
```

To fill the div.

Good luck!